# How to convert the list to datetime format in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert the time(2018-08-03 11:30:00) in the datetime format(year, month, day, hour, min, sec) from a list in python. Can anyone help? Thank you so much for your time.

This is the preset code.

```
from datetime import datetime
class Meeting:
    def __init__(self, start_time, end_time):
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time
```

My code:

```
for meeting in meetings:
    time1 = meeting.start_time 
    time2 = meeting.end_time 
    time3 = proposed_time      
    if time1 < time3 < time2:
        return False

    else:
        return True
```

Here are the values that can be passed through my code.

```
meetings = [Meeting(datetime(2018, 8, 1, 9, 0, 0), datetime(2018, 8, 1, 11, 0, 0))
```

Here are some values that CANNOT work for my code. So, I would like to convert for my code.

```
meetings = [Meeting(2018-08-03 11:30:00, 2018-08-03 13:15:00), Meeting(2018-08-07 15:15:00, 2018-08-07 16:45:00)]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: I didn't quite understand what do you want to do.. Do you want for this ```meetings = [Meeting(2018-08-03 11:30:00, 2018-08-03 13:15:00), Meeting(2018-08-07 15:15:00, 2018-08-07 16:45:00)] ``` to work?

Comment: Yes, this is one of the values that need to be tested with my code. I was wondering how I can extract the time (2018-08-03 11:30:00) from the meetings list to set as time1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to extract the time from the meetings list by making the time1, time2, and time3 as strings. Thanks for the inputs!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strptime` for conversion. `datetime.strptime('2018-08-03 11:30:00', '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')`

Comment: I know that I can use strptime; however, I have to put value individually as the date_string. So I was wondering how I can extract the time from the meetings list.